# Add row to a table: String literal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This is a part of my code used to add new row to a table. I have problem with compiling the code related to last two TD elements. There is always an error of string literal. Please help me to figure it out.

```
$( "#content tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + opr.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + flightNum.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + from_f.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='edit_but'>
          <div>
             <img src='images/edit.png' alt='Edit' />
          </div>
        </td>" +
        "<td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='deact_but' onclick="deactivateRow('+flightNum.val()+')">
          <div>
             <img src='images/delete.png' alt='Deactivate' />
          </div>        
        </td>"  + "</tr>" );
```

Comment: Hell you got a lot of unmatched and missing quotes, not just in the last two lines!

Comment: I don't think the onclick handler can be added that way.

Comment: @blazemonger - It can, but it's a stupid way to do it.

Comment: You can bypass things like this by cloning an existing table row and editing it. Add a class to each `td`, and then you can easily replace a cell's data with `.text()` before appending the clone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is a mess! there are so many quotes (`"`) missing and string concating (`+`) missing!

After a **lot** of fixing:

```
$( "#content tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + opr.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + flightNum.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + from_f.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='edit_but'>" +
          "<div>" +
             "<img src='images/edit.png' alt='Edit' />" +
          "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='deact_but' onclick='deactivateRow('" +flightNum.val()+")'>"  +
          "<div>" +
             "<img src='images/delete.png' alt='Deactivate' />" +
          "</div>"  +
        "</td></tr>" );​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: You don't need half of the quotes you added.  The last four lines were fine.

Comment: @PitaJ. You need them if they are not in a single line like he wrote! I'm not saying his code should be a model though.

Comment: No, he added tabs to format the html so it could be read by a real person.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#content tbody" ).append( "<tr><td>" + opr.val() + "</td><td>" + flightNum.val() + "</td><td>" + from_f.val() + "</td><td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='edit_but'><div><img src='images/edit.png' alt='Edit' /></div></td><td id=" + flightNum.val() + " class='deact_but' onclick='deactivateRow(" + flightNum.val() + ")'><div><img src='images/delete.png' alt='Deactivate' /></div></td></tr>" );
```

Comment: @Gusgus - That line should be fine, is `flightNum` defined?

Comment: Yes, flightNum is defined. Actually the code of 'gdoron' has been compiled fine. Thanks anyway.